# Opencart Multiple Option Qty's on the Category page

Tags: opencart

I want to know if there's a way to have it show on the Category page, the options that you can add multiple quantity's so for example size 5 as a option and be able to add any number quantity box?

here is a example:

http://www.tanai.com/jewelry-joyeria/steel-jewelry/en-l/jewelry-collection

TY!

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at these two extensions.

1. [Multiple Option Quantity](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3395&filter_search=option%20quantity&sort=e.date_modified&order=DESC)
2. [Product Accessories](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2274&filter_search=options&sort=e.date_modified&order=DESC)

No 1 seems to fit your needs more. If you're thinking of coding your own, you probably need to check out the Opencart forums first. I remember when I did Opencart, there was a boilerplate extension. =)

**Update**

To put it on the category page, you might have to combine the mod with some other mod that allows product ordering right from the category page. Personal experience with Opencart, unlikely the two extensions will just work together out of the box. =)

Comment: That's great ty!! is there a mod where is can show these on the category page? for a quick order type thing...

Comment: I think for that, you can probably code it into the tpl file yourself? It's probably easier to combine it with a `products on category page mod`.

Comment: Do you know how I can achieve this I'm new to php...  any HELP I'm stuck

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with specifics. Actually, you probably find more help on the exact code to run your Opencart installation on OC forums than here.

Answer (score 0):

you could try.
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=6234